# Need same date range for all items in list

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, append

I have

```
..........
wlst=['AA','BB']

DATE=pd.date_range(start='01-01-2019', periods = 3, freq = 'MS')
......................................
```

I need same month range for all items in list'wlst' as below

```
DATE Col2

2019-01-01 AA

2019-02-01 AA

2019-03-01 AA

2019-01-01 BB

2019-02-01 BB

2019-03-01 BB
```

I tried

```
dfpred =pd.DataFrame()

wlst=['AA','BB']

DATE=pd.date_range(start='01-01-2019', periods = 4, freq = 'MS')

for w in wlst:

    dfpred['DATE']=DATE

    dfpred['Col2']=w

dfpred
```

but i always get as below

```
2019-01-01 BB

2019-02-01 BB

2019-03-01 BB
```

Help

I have

```
wlst=['AA','BB']

DATE=pd.date_range(start='01-01-2019', periods = 3, freq = 'MS')

dfpred =pd.DataFrame()

wlst=['AA','BB']

DATE=pd.date_range(start='01-01-2019', periods = 4, freq = 'MS')

for w in wlst:

    dfpred['DATE']=DATE

    dfpred['Col2']=w

dfpred
```

output as below

```
2019-01-01 BB

2019-02-01 BB

2019-03-01 BB
```

no error nut get only last list name

Answer (score 0):

It works if you remove the loop and use a series.

```
dfpred['DATE']= DATE
dfpred['Col2']= pd.Series(wlst)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for response

Sorry but i could not make it work . I get NaN for last dates

I tried  as below
--------
dfpred =pd.DataFrame()
wlst=['AA','BB']

DATE=pd.date_range(start='01-01-2019', periods = 4, freq = 'MS')

dfpred['DATE']= DATE
dfpred['Col2']= pd.Series(wlst)

dfpred
---------
output

DATE  Col2
0     2019-01-01  AA    
1     2019-02-01  BB
2     2019-03-01  NaN
3     2019-04-01  NaN